# Intersection of Dense Sets of Parallel Lines

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis

The question is:

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the usual topology, let $S_i$ be a dense set of points that can be partitioned into parallel lines.  Let $m_i$ be the slope of these lines.  For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is the finite intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^n S_i$ nonempty (or even dense), provided $m_i\neq m_j$ for all $i,j\in 1,...,n$?

I understand that if the sets were open, then it would be true, and if they were arbitrary closed sets, the statement would be false, but this lies somewhere inbetween.  I suspect the intersection is indeed dense (and I strongly feel that the intersection is either empty or dense).  The $n=2$ case is obviously trivial, but I don't know how to move beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_0=0$ and $m_1=1$, and $S_0$ the set of horizontal lines $y=r$, $S_1$ the set of 45 degree lines $y=x+s$, where $r,s$ are taken to range over $\mathbb{Q}.$ Then so far we have that $S_0 \cap S_1$ is the set of "rational points" $(r_1,r_2)$ with each coordinate rational.

Now choose an irrational slope $m_2=\alpha.$ Furthermore choose any set (possibly empty, finite, or infinite) $A$ of rational points. For each point $(a,b) \in A$ the line $y-b=\alpha(x-a)$ meets the collection of rational points in the single point $(a,b)$ [another rational point would force $\alpha$ to be rational]. With these lines we've covered each point in $A$ exactly once. We can now fill out these lines to a dense set $S_2$ by throwing in all lines of the form $y=\alpha x+k$ where $k$ is not in the span over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the set $\{1,\alpha\}.$ It's easily shown none of the latter lines have any rational points on them.

So in this case, $S_0 \cap S_1 \cap S_2=A.$ In conclusion, at least for three sets, we can get any collection of rational points as such an intersection.

Comment: Nice answer...beat me to the punch.

Comment: @kigen The topic of lines meeting only one rational point came up on this site recently, so I was up on that, and had also looked into characterizing lines with no rational points.